# ASP.NET MVC 5 with NUnit and Moq; how to mock RoleManager so it is possible to setup it's extension methods?

Tags: asp.net, mocking, extension-methods

I have ASP.NET MVC 5 (.NET Framework) app with Entity Framework 6.2.
I'm using NUnit and Moq frameworks for testing.

I need to test if `roleResult.Succeeded` is true when  `RoleExists()` extension(static) method returns false for `"User"` role.

`HomeController.cs` :

```
private ApplicationDbContext _db;
private RoleManager<IdentityRole> _roleManager;
private ApplicationUserManager _userManager;

// Hard Entity Framework dependency (working application)
public HomeController()
{
    _db = new ApplicationDbContext();
    _roleManager = new RoleManager<IdentityRole>(new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(_db));
    _userManager = new ApplicationUserManager(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(_db));
    if (!_roleManager.RoleExists("User"))
    {
        IdentityResult roleResult = _roleManager.Create(new IdentityRole("User"));
    }
}

// Dependency injection only for testing
public HomeController(ApplicationDbContext context, ApplicationUserManager userManager, RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager, string role) // DI for testing
{
    _db = context;
    _roleManager = roleManager;
    _userManager = userManager;
    if (!_roleManager.RoleExists(role))
    {
        IdentityResult roleResult = _roleManager.Create(new IdentityRole(role));
    }
}
```

`HomeTest.cs` :

```
[Test]
public void HomeController_RoleDoesNotExist_AddRole()
{
    var mockContext = new Mock<ApplicationDbContext>();
    var mockUserManager = new Mock<ApplicationUserManager>();
    var mockRoleManager  = new Mock<RoleManager<IdentityRole>>();

    mockRoleManager.Setup(x => x.RoleExists("User")).Returns(false); // Moq says: nope :<

    var homeController = new HomeController(mockContext.Object, mockUserManager.Object, mockRoleManager.Object, "User");

    // Some Assert that I really don't know to deal with.
}
```

First: I don't know how implement testing code responsible for getting `roleResult.Succeeded` value.

Second: Moq cannot setup static methods and I don't know how to deal with it in my situation. I'll probably need to replace private properties in my `HomeController` class with some new interfaces but then my *Hard Entity Framework dependency* will stop working because of for example: `_db = new ApplicationDbContext() cannot be converted to IMyNewAppDbContext`.

Thanks for help.